How to create new timer trigger function using NodeJS azure and testing locally?
I am beginner for azure services learner. Need to know is there any documentation available to create timer trigger function using visual studio code in Nodejs.
Please share your guidance and recommendation to run locally function for testing.
Thanks!
Found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4, but as a beginner not understand how to start.

Follow the below steps to create a sample Timer trigger function in the Javascript V4 model and test it locally.
Steps :
Go to the Azure Extension in Visual Studio code and select create  Azure Functions > Create New Project > select the folder to create the function project as below,

Select the Javascript as the language as below,

Click on Model V4 as below,

Select the Timer trigger function as below,

Provide a name to the function as below,

Set the time for the timer trigger function as below,

Click on enter will create the Timer trigger function in the Javascript V4 model as below,

src/functions/timerTrigger1 :
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
app.timer('timerTrigger1', {
    schedule: '0 */5 * * * *',
    handler: (myTimer, context) => {
        context.log('Timer function processed request.');
    }
});

I have added the below test code for the above timer trigger function Javascript v4 model.
tests/timerTrigger1.test.js :
jest.mock('@azure/functions', () => {
  return {
      app: {
          timer: jest.fn()
      }
  };
});
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const context = {
  log: jest.fn()
};
let handler;
beforeAll(() => {
  app.timer.mockImplementation((name, options) => {
      handler = options.handler;
  });
  require('../src/functions/timerTrigger1');
});
describe('timerTrigger1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  test('should log the expected message', () => {
      const myTimer = {}; 
      handler(myTimer, context);
      expect(context.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Timer function processed request.');
  });
});

package.json :
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "sinon": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "main": "src/functions/*.js"
}

Output :
I successfully ran the timer trigger function and test code as below.

